# PTVS no intellisense in IronPython project

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

I'm using VS2013 with PTVS and have the problem, that i have no IntelliSense support for self written c#/.net assemblies. The assemblies are all referenced in the project. I'm using .net framework 4.5.1. The referenced system dlls are available via IntelliSense (like `System` or `System.Data`).

IntelliSense also works for custom dlls, if i use `clr.AddReference` at the top of a script. But this is no solution. What am i doing wrong?

Maybe some one has a solution, thank you!

Comment: Why is `clr.AddReference` not a solution, given that you need to use it to actually load the assembly?

Comment: We load all assemblies in our c# core and only use VS as ide.

Comment: What PTVS does is basically feed those `clr.AddReference` lines to IronPython, and lets it resolve things (so what you see in Intellisense is exactly what it'll load at runtime). If those aren't there, then you will only get the preloaded assemblies like `System`.

So there's no solution right now unless you put those `AddReference` calls somewhere (I don't think it needs to be the same .py file even). Feel free to file a feature request to address this scenario on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. Maybe you could copy the comment as an answer...

Comment: Putting the `AddReference` calls in a separate file will hit another bug right now (which is already fixed, but not in our current release). If you really don't want to execute them, put them in an `if False` block - our code analysis will still notice them but IronPython won't run them.